# i want to add background image in this coding

Tags: php, css

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php 
session_start();
include('./db_connect.php');
  ob_start();
  // if(!isset($_SESSION['system'])){

    $system = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM system_settings")->fetch_array();
    foreach($system as $k => $v){
      $_SESSION['system'][$k] = $v;
    }
  // }
  ob_end_flush();
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
header("location:index.php?page=home");

?>
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<body class="hold-transition login-page bg-black">
  <h2><b><?php echo $_SESSION['system']['name'] ?> - Admin</b></h2>
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="#" class="text-white"></a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <form action="" id="login-form">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required placeholder="Email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
          <label for="">Login As</label>
          <select name="login" id="" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
            <option value="3">Student</option>
            <option value="2">Faculty</option>
            <option value="1">Admin</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    start_load()
    if($(this).find('.alert-danger').length > 0 )
      $(this).find('.alert-danger').remove();
    $.ajax({
      url:'ajax.php?action=login',
      method:'POST',
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      error:err=>{
        console.log(err)
        end_load();

      },
      success:function(resp){
        if(resp == 1){
          location.href ='index.php?page=home';
        }else{
          $('#login-form').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger">Username or password is incorrect.</div>')
          end_load();
        }
      }
    })
  })
  })
</script>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

how I might be able to include the background image into it, as well as specifics regarding the manner in which this procedure will be carried out. Which of the following courses of action do you recommend I take? The PHP scripting language was used to create this paragraph. Please do not be hesitant to ask any questions that you may have and do not hesitate to do so. For each and every one of you doing this, I will always have the deepest thanks and admiration in the world. My education in computer programming is only just getting begun.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img src=”https://example.com/Image”>` with your image url and set position: absolute;

For the child objects use position: relative;